# How to prove that the sequence $x_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sin k\,$ is divergent using Cauchy's divergence criterion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Criterion: $x_n$ converges if and only if $\;\forall \varepsilon>0 \;\exists N=N(\varepsilon)>0 \; \forall n\ge N \;\forall p\in\mathbb{N}: \;\; |x_{n+p}-x_n|>\varepsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use Cauchy's criterion, then the point is the following formula: $$\sum_{i = n + 1}^{n + p}\sin(i) = \frac{1}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2})}(\cos(n + \frac{1}{2}) - \cos(n + p + \frac{1}{2})).$$

Proof: use the fact that $2\sin(\frac{1}{2})\sin(i) = \cos(i - \frac{1}{2}) - \cos(i + \frac{1}{2})$.

Now you may try to complete the proof of your original problem.

---

Note that, however, the divergence actually follows from a simpler fact that $\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\sin(k)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The simpler fact is Cauchy's condition for $p=1$. Disproving one case disproves the $\forall p$ in the original condition.

Comment: Right. One may argue anyhow one likes.

Comment: @WhatsUp, Thanks for this simple proof!